# Google Maps API Mail

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Today I have received an email from Google Maps API. My Site would have sent more than 15k daily map load requests or 2k web service requests. I checked the user requestions for my site in the developer console, and there are far less than 2k daily. Should i pay attention to this email from google?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTVIq.jpg)

Comment: In the mail is written "in the last 30 days" not "daily".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [launch blog](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html) post for full details of the changes 
and the [developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update)  for more info. 
The email mentions 15k map loads or 2k service requests which include
[directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding), etc